# Selenium Python drop down staleElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have a dropdown that contains elements, each of which when clicked generates a table on the webpage. In that table, there is one column where I need to click in order to download the target file.

I have written code that does the job for the first element in the dropdown but when I try to iterate for the second element in the dropdown the program throws an error saying -
"StaleElementReferenceException: **Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"**

Code Snippt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.delete_all_cookies()

def fetch_d(driver,locator):
    dropdown_menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
    dropdown_menu_list = Select(dropdown_menu).options
    counter = 0
    for i in dropdown_menu_list:
        print("I am in counter no", counter, "\n" )
        tmp = i.get_property("value")  #---------- This is the part which throws error during the second iteration

        locator1 = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ddlacname [value='" + str(tmp) +"']")
        tmp1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator1))

        print(tmp1.text)
        time.sleep(3)
        if counter == 0:  #Skipping first iteration because the first item in drop down containers just the label information of the drop-dwon
            pass
        else:
            tmp1.click()
            locator2 = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#GridView1") 
            #----------------------------------------------------------
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator2))
            a_tags = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            for i in a_tags:
                i.click() # This is the part which downloads the file from the target hyperlink
            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        counter+=1 

#Method call
fetch_d(driver,(By.ID, "ddlacname"))
```

dropdown_menu_list = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="a95b8c99-c9a5-463f-bc43-5ebe65f5b0f8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="f356a61c-1d2b-40cc-871d-e3f0c13d29c6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="65221723-60bd-4501-91fa-40a83beb7eaa")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="dd49da85-603b-42a0-adbd-a94fb5449942")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="2bef7d17-35b6-4384-a609-0eb1f0314ddb")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="0ec7bd95-1dfe-4ffe-9c89-7825bf38f11d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="e3233e15-2120-4682-8e95-2c0bd49587b5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="857e51d1-9f12-4034-908e-850d008b8e1a")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="a4ece66e-4e34-49f6-b5fa-9111916daf7f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="d85e2636-0dbf-41d5-87bb-168bd0942d51")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="b98112f3-fed2-429b-9b7e-d6510f99ca80")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="c9fe6ddc-9e34-495c-8ff8-d523e0c8099c")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="ddf6b811-d389-4f25-ad3e-b2803aeb2fc5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7af50d60028e2c39734117b81e9514e", element="bfce4bd8-ef4e-44c5-81e7-592115341fa0")>]

[image]

Comment: Please add target URL then we can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that. This is a postgrad college project which involves scrapping government data. I'll check with the college authorities if that can be done. If possible, I'll do that.